# RecyclerView doesn't update views after notifyItemInserted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-adapter

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1kOv.png)

I have a Recyclerview using GridLayoutManager like above.
It has a few empty items (like a placeholder) when initialized.
When I press the button, upload an image to my server and bind it to view after success.
On the other hand, when I press an uploaded image, call delete API and remove it from view and add a new empty item at the same time.
The problem I'm facing is it doesn't update the view when I add a new item even though the data is updated.
It seems like a newly added item uses a deleted item's view. (background color, click listener etc)

It is successful when I use `notifyDataSetChanged`.

My method is below

```
fun deleteItem(pictureId: Int) {
    val position = mItems.indexOfFirst {
        if (it is PictureItem) {
            it.userImage?.imageId == pictureId
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
    mItems.removeAt(position)
    mItems.add(PictureItem())
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyItemInserted(itemCount - 1)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemCount)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = mItems[holder.adapterPosition]
    when (item) {
        is PictureItem -> (holder as? PictureViewHolder)!!.bind(item)
        ~~~
    }
}

private class PictureViewHolder(private val context: Context, view: View,
                                   private val clickListener: PictureClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val mImageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(id)
    private val mOverlayText: TextView = view.findViewById(id)
    fun bind(item: PictureItem) {

        if (item.userImage == null) {
            mImageView.setImageResource(colorres)
            return
        }
        bindSubPictureUrl(context, item.userImage!!)
        mImageView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.clicked(imageId))
        }
    }

    private fun bindSubPictureUrl(context: Context, userImage: UserImage) {
        Glide.~~~.into(mImageView)
        mOverlayText.visibility = if (someCondition) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }

}
```

Comment: `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemCount)` what's the point of this call? You are not changing any items in between removed item and last position. I think this should be ommited. Also how does your `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemViewType` look?

Comment: @Pawel   I added extra code. I call notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemCount) to notify other items to change their position as well. For example, a user has already uploaded four pictures, and delete the second one,  third and fourth items position change as well.

Comment: you don't need to do that, `notifyItemRemoved` is enough to shift position of items behind it.

Comment: I removed `notifyItemRangeChanged` , but it doesn’t fix

Answer (score 0):

In your `onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)` you have the `position` argument. 
What is `adapterPosition` that you use in  
`val item = mItems[holder.adapterPosition]`

Shouldn't you use `position` there?

Comment: I used  `position` argument previously, and the result is same

Comment: The thing is you must use `position` and then try to fix other issues.